# Left div container as links/nav which upon click of a link, displays content in right div container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I apologize in advance if this sounds confusing...Let's get started shall we !

Okay, my questions at hand is how to make 2 separate div conatiners, 1 on the left and 1 on the right side aligned side-by-side horizontally.  That I know how to do, however, I'd like to have on the left side links or a nav bar going vertical in that div container.  And upon click of a link, the content gets displayed into the right div and so forth with the other links on click.

So basically, left side would ideally be the menu/nav bar full of links that go vertical.  Upon click of a link, the content get's displayed in the right div container.

Which method would be best to use and how would I do/implement it...

1.) Use the Target: psuedo elements in css?

2.) Use Javascript to perform this.

I'd like transition effects as well, so if anyone could help guide me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it!  Also, if you have a jsfiddle, that would be best as well!

I unfortunately do not have any code to provide atm except for the left and right div containers and links/nav in the left div container.  Here is that:

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 420px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#left_div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: #333;
  float: left;
}
#left_div a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0; /*-- Have, but atm cannot remember --*/
  margin: 0; /*-- Have, but atm cannot remember --*/
  color: #CCC;
  font: 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-align: center;
}
#left_div a:hover, a.active {
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.09);
  color: #FFF;
}
#right_div {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: #333;
  float: left;
}
#right_div .container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 380px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  background: #222;
  float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left_div">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div id="right_div">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Again this is just a rough draft of the code, but hopefully it helps with what I'm asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/butani_vijay010/85WVs/) may be helpful to you.

or

code :

**HTML** :

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left_div">
        <a href="#" id="link1">Link1</a>
        <a href="#" id="link2">Link2</a>
        <a href="#" id="link3">Link3</a>
        <a href="#" id="link4">Link4</a>
    </div>
    <div id="right_div">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript** ( Jquery )

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link1").click(function(){

        animateDiv("right_div .container");
        $("#right_div .container").html("You have Click on line1");

    });
    $("#link2").click(function(){
    animateDiv("right_div .container");
        $("#right_div .container").html("You have Click on line2");

    });
    $("#link3").click(function(){
    animateDiv("right_div .container");
        $("#right_div .container").html("You have Click on line3");

    });
    $("#link4").click(function(){
    animateDiv("right_div .container");
        $("#right_div .container").html("You have Click on line4");

    });

    function animateDiv(id){
         //perform your animation here
    }
});
```

**CSS**:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 420px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#left_div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: #333;
  float: left;
}
#left_div a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0; /*-- Have, but atm cannot remember --*/
  margin: 0; /*-- Have, but atm cannot remember --*/
  color: #CCC;
  font: 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-align: center;
}
#left_div a:hover, a.active {
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.09);
  color: #FFF;
}
#right_div {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: #333;
  float: left;
}
#right_div .container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 380px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  background: #222;
  float: left;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Gracious Mate ;)  It's not exactly what I want, however, that fiddle will most definitely guide me in the right direction, so Thank You very much!